# Web scraping API runs a bad request error

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape the following website using Python for the estimated annual yield of each product:
https://www.binance.com/en/lending#lending-demandDeposits

I am trying to do so via an API:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#savings-endpoints

However, open running the following code, I get error 400 (bad request):

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/lending/daily/product/list")
print(response.status_code)
```

How do I go about solving the problem?

Comment: You need an API key!

Comment: Try this link it is giving data which you are trying to get from the API https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/friendly/lending/daily/product/list?pageSize=100&pageIndex=1